# Trying to accommodate relative defined date, such as 5 days ago, into my fixed date condition in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, date, sorting

I'm trying to condition my WHERE clause to accommodate relatively defined dates into my date filter. I'm pretty confused what type I need to use, if it's CONVERT or TO_DATE function, or if I need to put a CASE WHEN statement into my code.

This is the code that I have written so far:

```
WHERE event_create_verified_user_success.created_at_utc_date
BETWEEN DATE '2021-11-29' AND DATE '2021-12-05'
```

And this is the condition of the activity I need to finish:

> If the desired date-period is not set manually using fixed dates like from “2021-11-29”
> to “2021-12-05”, how would you change the where-clause to consider all data from relative
> defined dates: “consider messages created between 10 days and 5 days ago (inclusive)”

I've only started PostgreSQL yesterday and the last time I've handle SQL was probably 4 years ago so I'm pretty confused at how much SQL has changed since then.

Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

The basic syntax hasn't really changed in the last 4 years (or even 15 years).

You can use `current_date` to obtain "today's date". You can subtract days from that

```
where ... between current_date - 10 and current_date - 5
```

If `created_at_utc_date` is a `timestamp` (= date **and** time) rather than a `date` (=date *without* time) it's better to use a range query though:

```
where created_at_utc_date >= current_date - 10
  and created_at_utc_date < current_date - 4
```

Note the `<` combined with the *next* day you want to compare with.

Comment: Thank you so much! Tried that and it worked. 
I might have gotten too intimidated by the problem that I've remembered things wrong. Wish me good luck with trying to learn SQL all over again!